# Can use joblib dump many object?

Tags: python, svm, pca, joblib

I have this code. Can I save 'pca' and 'svm_clf' to one file by using joblib.dump? If not, is there any other way to do this?

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import svm

X = [[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,7,0],[1,3,4,5,6,7,9,5,1]]
Y = [1,0]
#pca
pca = decomposition.PCA(0.98)
X_new = pca.fit_transform(X)
svm_clf = svm.LinearSVC()
#svm model
svm_clf = SVC(C=1, kernel='rbf')
svm_clf.fit(X_new, Y)
#save model
joblib.dump(pca, 'model.sav')
joblib.dump(svm_clf, 'model.sav')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
joblib.dump([pca, svm_clf], 'model.sav', compress=1)
```

And then use the models like:

```
pca, svm_clf = joblib.load('model.sav')
```

Probably a nicer way is to define a pipeline if you want to use these two models together and dump the pipeline:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
pipeline = make_pipeline(pca, svm_clf)
joblib.dump(pipeline, 'model.sav')
```

Comment: Thank you. When I call model by joblib.load('model.sav'), can I use it to predict as a normal SVM model ?

Comment: Fairly simple and understandable answer. Thanks and upvoted!