# Pickling/saving/joblib dumping a complex class to a single file

Tags: python, pickle, joblib

Below is a minimal working example. This is a tiny representation of my problem and not nearly as complex as what I actually have to work with.

Suppose I have a class with a few complex objects contained within the class, like sci-kit learn classes. I know that I can save the objects like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from joblib import dump, load

class SeveralPickels:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.lm1 = LinearRegression()
        self.lm2 = LinearRegression()
        
    def save(self):
        dump(self.lm1, f'lm1.joblib')
        dump(self.lm2, f'lm2.joblib')
        
    def load(self):
        self.lm1 = load(f'lm1.joblib')
        self.lm2 = load(f'lm2.joblib')

sp = SeveralPickels()
sp.save()

sp2 = SeveralPickels()
sp2.load()
```

What I would really like to do is save both(read *many*) of the objects to the same file, in some way. Why? Because the class that I actually want to do something like this on has several complex, yet completely picklable/joblib.dumpable objects. I've thought about using hdf5, but that seems to prefer numerical data, not objects. What would be a good way to do a thing like this, or do I have to grit my teeth and bear having to save/load from several files?

Comment: To pickle multiple objects in one file, simply pickle a list (or other container) containing those objects.

Comment: Question already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312742/can-use-joblib-dump-many-object My google foo is weak